# Texture crop replacement in OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to upgrade code which uses OpenGLES1 to ES2. The conversion is more or less understandable however for these lines I could not find alternative in ES2. Not even sure why it is necessary.

```
GLint crop[4] = { 0, h, w, -h };
glTexParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_CROP_RECT_OES, crop);
```

Comment: `GL_TEXTURE_CROP_RECT_OES` belongs to the OpenGL extension [OES_draw_texture](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/OES/OES_draw_texture.txt). You cannot use it with OpenGL ES 2.0. You need to draw a rectangle and set the texture coordinate attribute that corresponds to the cropping rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

if it is for drawing animation then use UV coordinates, it is faster.
If you need part of the texture use

```
Bitmap newbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(oldbitmap, x,y,w,h)
GLUtils.texImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, newbitmap , 0);
```